# Representing linear maps geometrically

Tags: linear-algebra

> Describe the following linear maps $T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ geometrically. 
>   $(x, y)$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we write $T(x, y)$ rather than $T((x, y))$.
>   $$T(x, y) = (−2x, −2y)$$

so is the answer to the question just a graph with the plots $(-2,0)$ and $(0,-2)$

Comment: Linear maps from one space to another do a lot more than just map one point to another point.  The type of answer that they are expecting will likely involve the words "stretch," "rotate," "reflect," or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [geogebra page](https://www.geogebra.org/graphing/rj9fj72z), can you say something about the linear map? In particular, can you think of it as a collection of steps of the form:

[image]

- $p = (x, y)$: the original vector
- $q = -p = (-x, -y)$: the vector pointing in (???) direction

  > The direction opposite to $p$
- $r = 2q = (-2x, -2y)$: the vector that is like q, with (???)

  > The same direction as $q$, scaled by a factor of 2.